How to correctly type a JavaScript proxy handler in TypeScript for (Angular Signals-like) reactive state management?
I wanted to create a short documentation and explain the principle of Angular Signals using JavaScript proxies in an example. Then the question came up: could I quickly write it in TypeScript and set up the types? I said, of course, no problem, but then, surprise—somehow the types didn't fit anymore.
How can I use the correct types e.g. in:
target[property as keyof StateType] = value as StateType[keyof StateType];

outputs an error:
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)

This is the whole example (Online TS Playground):
type StateType = {
    count: number;
    name: string;
};

const state: StateType = {
    count: 0,
    name: 'React'
};

function onStateChange<K extends keyof StateType>(property: K, value: StateType[K]): void {
    console.log(`The property "${property}" was changed to "${value}"`);
}

const handler: ProxyHandler<StateType> = {
    set(target, property, value) {
        if (property in target) {
            target[property as keyof StateType] = value as StateType[keyof StateType];
            onStateChange(property as keyof StateType, value as StateType[keyof StateType]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

const proxyState = new Proxy(state, handler);

proxyState.count = 1; 
proxyState.name = 'Angular'; 


Hope this helps: Playground

Oh, that's also very elegant, thank you @HairyHandKerchief23

Okay, I've got it. I would have needed to spend another 15 minutes on it. So that others don’t run into the same problem, here is the solution (1st Attempt):
type StateType = {
    count: number;
    name: string;
};

const state: StateType = {
    count: 0,
    name: 'React'
};

function onStateChange<K extends keyof StateType>(property: K, value: StateType[K]): void {
    console.log(`The property "${property}" was changed to "${value}"`);
}

const handler: ProxyHandler<StateType> = {
    set<K extends keyof StateType>(
        target: StateType,
        property: K,
        value: StateType[K]
    ): boolean {
        if (property in target) {
            target[property] = value;
            onStateChange(property, value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

const proxyState = new Proxy(state, handler);

proxyState.count = 1;
proxyState.name = 'Angular';

Short Explanation:
Generics in set Method ensures that prop and value both are correct typed due to StateType.
Edit & Update (2nd attempt, simplified, Online TS Playground):
type StateType = {
    count: number;
    name: string;
};

const state: StateType = {
    count: 0,
    name: 'React'
};

function onStateChange<K extends keyof StateType>(property: K, value: StateType[K]): void {
    console.log(`The property "${property}" was changed to "${value}"`);
}

const handler: ProxyHandler<StateType> = {
    set(
        target: StateType,
        property: string | symbol,
        value: any
    ): boolean {
        if (property in target) {
            const key = property as keyof StateType;
            (target[key] as any) = value;
            onStateChange(key, value as StateType[typeof key]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

const proxyState = new Proxy(state, handler);

proxyState.count = 1; 
proxyState.name = 'Angular';


Something's wrong with this thought, this implies that property extends keyof StateType, which is not always the case, that's why he's checking property in target, a wider union does not extend a narrower one. Playground

Many thanks @HairyHandKerchief23, You're correct that property in a Proxy's set handler can be any string or symbol, not just keys of StateType. The in check is indeed there to handle cases where the property might not be a key of the target object. I've added an update addresses this issue. Would you please re-check it again.
